# Check class names of nested divs || Ember/Mocha/Chai tests?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, mocha.js, integration-testing, chai

So I am writing integration tests using Mocha and Chai.
I am new to tests.

Long story short.

I installed couple Chai jQuery plugins like *chai-dom* , *chai-jq* and *chai-jquery*.

I am running the tests by "***ember test --server***"

I have a div with a **".navigation"** class.
This div has three nested divs, each with a unique class.

In my tests, I am checking if the parent div exists:

**should.exist('.navigation');**

How can I "expect" the other 3 nested divs to have the classes I want?

I want something like:

**expect($('.navigation)).children[0].to.have.class('flex1')**

OR

**expect($('.navigation)).children().to.have.class('flex1, flex2, flex3')**

OR

**expect($('.navigation)).descendants.to.have.class('flex1, flex2, flex3')**

Something like that..?

Same goes to IDs I believe?

Thank you in advance.

Mo.

Comment: Could you please write what is the ember code that works you've written for `should.exist('.navigation');` condition test. Maybe it will help us to write the rest.

Comment: @AhmetEmreKılınç
 `describe.only('Show navigation bar', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      visit('/');
      fillIn('#member_login', 'user');
      fillIn('#member_password', 'pass');
      should.exist('.login_button');
      click('.login_button');
    });
    it('shows navigation bar', function() {
      should.exist('.navigation');
      expect($('.navigation').children()).to.have.length(3)
      **THE REST OF THE CODE SHOULD GO HERE**
    });
  });`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found out that the best to do is the following:

**`should.exist('.navigation');`**

**`expect($('.navigation').children()).to.have.length(3)`**

**`should.exist($('.navigation').children('.flex-left'));`**

OR more assertion would be: `expect($('.navigation').children('.flex-left')).to.have.length(1)`

**`expect($('.navigation').children('.flex-left').children()).to.have.length(2)`**